Movie where bad guy is killed by dog race track hare
Here's what I remember.
The main bad guy (maybe Brian Dennehy) is killed at end by a metal hare on a track at a dog racing track.
Other details, the protagonist is a young adult, hired to drive a red car cross country. Stops in a small town, in a bar or restaurant gets into an altercation and the son of the main bad guy ends up dead and the protagonist blamed.
I think this movie was late eighties, maybe early nineties.

Is there really nothing else you remember? Any other details or descriptions that may help identification? If it might have starred Brian Dennehy, did his filmography bring anything up that's likely?

One of my fave movies. Its called RUN. 1991. Stars Patrick Dempsey. The guy he gets into altercation with is called Halloran and is played by Alan C Peterson. This guy is jealous because Charlie(Dempsey) attracts the attention of Kelly Preston (who becomes a sort of side kick later on) and beats him at poker. During altercation Halloran slips hits his head and dies. It turns out Hallorans Dad is kingpin of crime type character called Boss Halloran played by Ken Pogue. As a result no witnesses will come forward and both criminals and cops hunt Charlie for reward. Boss Halloran is eventually killed by race hare at race track. Great film. Very underrated.
